# Update Form Hidden Field Value wit button ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of popover buttons that will open the same form. Now I need the button id value as hidden field inside the form.

html buttons:

```
<a type="button" class="pop" data-toggle="popover" id="1">Button 1</a>
<a type="button" class="pop" data-toggle="popover" id="2">Button 2</a>
<a type="button" class="pop" data-toggle="popover" id="3">Button 3</a>
...
```

popover form:

```
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
<form>
<input name="name" type="hidden" value="ButtonIDvalue">
...
```

popover js:

```
$('.pop').popover({ 
        html : true,
        content: function() {
            return $("#popover-content").html();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the element that triggered the popover as `this` within the function bound to `content`. So you could update your code to be:

```
$('.pop').popover({ 
        html : true,
        content: function() {
            $('#hidden-input').val(this.id);
            return $("#popover-content").html();
        }
    });
```

Of course using whatever the correct selector is for your hidden input field.